# DevExpress routing appears to break with dotnet core 3.1

Tags: .net-core, devexpress-gridcontrol

I have the following `DxDatagrid` block in my `dotnet core webapp index.cshtml` page:

```
@(Html.DevExtreme().DataGrid<UserModel>()
    .ID("grid-container")
    .ShowBorders(true)
    .DataSource(d => d.Mvc().Controller("UserSearch").LoadAction("Get").Key("UserId"))
    .Selection(s => s
        .Mode(SelectionMode.Multiple)
        .SelectAllMode(SelectAllMode.Page)
        )
```

With this code in place and using `dotnet core 2.2` the datasource makes a call to:

```
http://localhost:5000/api/UserSearch/Get?skip=0&take=10&requireTotalCount=true&_=1600859370033
```

Having updated to dotnet core 3.1 and updated the DevExpress references in the `csproj` and `_Layout.cshtml` files, the routing now attempts to call:

```
http://localhost:5000/?skip=0&take=10&requireTotalCount=true&_=1600859693687
```

The `startup.cs` is this:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Globalization;
using System.IO;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Builder;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpsPolicy;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Localization;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using AccessUsers.Middleware;
using AccessUsers.Models;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.HttpOverrides;

namespace WebAppTest
{
    public class Startup
    {
        private readonly IConfiguration _config;
        private readonly AppSettings _appSettings;

        public Startup(IConfiguration config)
        {
            _config = config;
            _appSettings = _config.Get<AppSettings>();
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
        public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
        {
            services.Configure<CookiePolicyOptions>(options =>
            {
                // This lambda determines whether user consent for non-essential cookies is needed for a given request.
                options.CheckConsentNeeded = context => false;
                // options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.None;

                options.MinimumSameSitePolicy = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
                options.OnAppendCookie = cookieContext => cookieContext.CookieOptions.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
                options.OnDeleteCookie = cookieContext => cookieContext.CookieOptions.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Unspecified;
            });

            services.Configure<AppSettings>(_config);

            services.AddSingleton<APIService>();
            services.AddSingleton<UserService>();
            services.AddSingleton<ShipToService>();

            services.AddApplicationInsightsTelemetry();

            services.AddLocalization(options => options.ResourcesPath = "Resources");
            services.AddSession();
            services.AddMemoryCache();
            
            services.AddRazorPages().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
                options.SerializerSettings.ContractResolver = new Newtonsoft.Json.Serialization.DefaultContractResolver();
                options.SerializerSettings.ReferenceLoopHandling = Newtonsoft.Json.ReferenceLoopHandling.Ignore;
            }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters();

            services.UseOpenIDConnectMiddleware(new OpenIDConnectMiddlewareOptions
            {
                BaseUrl = _appSettings.API.BaseUrl,
                AppName = _appSettings.AppName,
                ClientId = _appSettings.API.ClientId,
                ClientSecret = _appSettings.API.ClientSecret,
                Secure = !_appSettings.Local
            });
        }

        // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
        public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
        {
            app.UseForwardedHeaders(new ForwardedHeadersOptions
            {
                ForwardedHeaders = ForwardedHeaders.XForwardedProto
            });

            if (_appSettings.Local)
            {
                app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
            }
            else
            {
                app.UseExceptionHandler("/Error");
                app.UseHsts();
                app.UseGlobalLoginMiddleware();
                app.UseHttpsRedirection();
            }

            app.UseStaticFiles();
            app.UseCookiePolicy();

            app.UseRouting();
            app.UseAuthentication();
            app.UseAuthorization();

            app.UseSession();

            app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
                endpoints.MapRazorPages();
            });

            CultureInfo[] allCultures = CultureInfo.GetCultures(CultureTypes.AllCultures);
            string location = Path.GetDirectoryName(System.Reflection.Assembly.GetEntryAssembly().Location);
            var supportedCultures = allCultures.Where(c => Directory.Exists(Path.Combine(location, c.Name)) && c.LCID != 127).ToList();

            app.UseRequestLocalization(new RequestLocalizationOptions
            {
                DefaultRequestCulture = new RequestCulture("en-US"),
                SupportedCultures = supportedCultures,
                SupportedUICultures = supportedCultures
            });
        }
    }
}
```

The `csproj` contains this:

```
<Project Sdk="Microsoft.NET.Sdk.Web">

  <PropertyGroup>
    <TargetFramework>netcoreapp3.1</TargetFramework>
    <AspNetCoreHostingModel>OutOfProcess</AspNetCoreHostingModel>
  </PropertyGroup>


  <ItemGroup>
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.OpenIdConnect" Version="3.1.6" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc.NewtonsoftJson" Version="3.1.7" />
    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Protocols.OpenIdConnect" Version="6.7.1" />

    <PackageReference Include="DevExtreme.AspNet.Data" Version="2.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="DevExtreme.AspNet.Core" Version="20.1.7" />

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.IdentityModel.Tokens" Version="6.7.1" />
    <PackageReference Include="System.IdentityModel.Tokens.Jwt" Version="6.7.1" />

    <PackageReference Include="Microsoft.ApplicationInsights.AspNetCore" Version="2.14.0" />

    <PackageReference Include="Amazon.Lambda.AspNetCoreServer" Version="5.0.0" />
  </ItemGroup>

</Project>
```

The `controller.cs` contains this:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.IO;
using System.Text.Json;
using AccessUsers.Models;
using DevExtreme.AspNet.Data;
using DevExtreme.AspNet.Mvc;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace WebAppTest.Pages
{
    [Route("api/[controller]/[action]")]
    public class UserSearchController : Controller
    {
        private readonly UserService _userService;

        public UserSearchController(UserService userService)
        {
            _userService = userService;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        public object Get(DataSourceLoadOptions loadOptions)
        {
            var result =  DataSourceLoader.Load(GetProfiles(user:new UserModel(),useDummyData: true), loadOptions);

            return result;
        }
```

The `_Layout.cshtml` contains this:

```
<script src="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/20.1.7/js/dx.all.js" integrity="sha384-LAn+t9UxSqkm8biNuoUbJcohKoYmbiFRfVLERIJ4I3RyEpAIBizEcIztuXPG9Cqg sha512-OAjfsw+eXv345AD9H6kDJLChXetpJD6ChGgDvjVIEumiHYulOLXIO/Do5gxljW2GUgpObic42JyS8a0wZqb1Fw==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn3.devexpress.com/jslib/20.1.7/js/dx.aspnet.mvc.js" integrity="sha384-5rtF4jUX5Hez5YwkW7PHC/0XplJQS26qVUCfec8fBX0IkoR1y35EXHkZDbgeMh3x sha512-0eJebJTnN45FCtUOrVqxk5p73OMWsx94vLQpnlRtDp/CKbssiUR0j0os+0y01fvzDtdtnEKSeau32g30fgtrYQ==" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
```

As specified here:
https://js.devexpress.com/Documentation/Guide/Common/Distribution_Channels/CDN/

I'm sure it's the change to `dotnet core 3.1` which caused the routing to break because the functionality of the application hasn't changed, but I can't see what specifically breaks it.

Comment: Which DxDatagrid verison are you using? .NET Core 3.x is a major version. It's *expected* to have breaking changes. Third-party libraries built for older versions may have problems, or you may *not* be using an MVC controller any more. BTW you didn't post the most important part of the code, the controller. This isn't about routing, it's how the grid helpers generate URLs

Comment: `d.Mvc().Controller("UserSearch").LoadAction("Get")` is responsible for generating `/api/UserSearch/Get?` using *reflection* and the names specified as strings. If the names are wrong, in an unexpected namespace or using an unexpected base class, that call chain can easily fail. There's no `AddMvc()` in your configuration so `d.Mvc()` may fail right from the start

Comment: I have updated my post with the controller snippet.

Comment: How do I find the version number of the datagrid I'm using? I assumed it would be 20.1.7 as that is the DevExpress package version.

Comment: Can you call that controller directly in the first place? There's no `AddMvc()` or `AddControllers()` in your Startup, only `AddRazorPages()`

Comment: Docs state: "This method configures the MVC services for the commonly used features for pages. This combines the effects of MvcCoreServiceCollectionExtensions.AddMvcCore(IServiceCollection), MvcCoreMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.AddAuthorization(IMvcCoreBuilder), MvcDataAnnotationsMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.AddDataAnnotations(IMvcCoreBuilder), TagHelperServicesExtensions.AddCacheTagHelper(IMvcCoreBuilder), and MvcRazorPagesMvcCoreBuilderExtensions.AddRazorPages(IMvcCoreBuilder)."

Comment: But no `AddControllers`. In fact, if you check the source you'll see that `AddMvc` calls `AddRazorPages`. Again, can you call that API at all?

Comment: From the same doc page you posted `To add services for controllers for APIs call AddControllers(IServiceCollection).`

Comment: I tried that and it didn't work. What did work in the end was adding 'endpoints.MapControllers();' after 'endpoints.MapRazorPages();'.

Comment: The point is, you need to add Controller support

Comment: Yes, sorry - I added that on a separate line above 'services.AddRazorPages()...' (did not allow me to chain it; thought it was already there when I wrote back later on.)

Answer (score 0):

`Startup.ConfigureServices` doesn't add support for controllers, only for Razor Pages with :

```
services.AddRazorPages().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
        ...
        }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
```

From the [Remarks in the method's documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.extensions.dependencyinjection.mvcservicecollectionextensions.addrazorpages?view=aspnetcore-3.1)

> This method configures the MVC services for the commonly used features for pages.

> *To add services for controllers for APIs call AddControllers(IServiceCollection).*

The controller is never registered right now, so the code that tries to generate the action URL

```
.DataSource(d => d.Mvc().Controller("UserSearch").LoadAction("Get")
```

fails to find anything and returns an empty string.

To fix this, add controller support :

```
services.AddControllers().AddNewtonsoftJson(options => {
        ...
        }).AddXmlSerializerFormatters();
services.AddRazorPages();
```

Controllers should be added in the endpoint routing code in `Configure` as well, with [MapControllers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.builder.controllerendpointroutebuilderextensions.mapcontrollers?view=aspnetcore-3.1) :

```
app.UseEndpoints(endpoints => {
    endpoints.MapRazorPages();
    endpoints.MapControllers();
});
```